# How to install a custom certificate in Symfony server?

Tags: symfony, command-line, console, ssl-certificate, symfony-console

With `server:ca:install` on the Symfony console an SSL certificate can be generated and installed.

**Is it possible / How to install an existing one, created separately (instead of the auto-generated one)?**

Background: I need a certificate, that contains a specific IP as "alternative name".

Answer (score 2):

`symfony server:ca:install` command creates and install certificates in user home directory `(~)` under `.symfony5/certs` folder you can replace generated certs with the existing ones here.

**Note:** Before replacing you can backup existing certs for later usage Or you can just regenerate new certs with the same command.