# Deploy a symfony app : Apache or Symfony server

Tags: apache, symfony, web-deployment

I am currently trying to deploy a Symfony 5.4 application for production with HTTPS on an apache server on which I could access the web app with https://servername/ and end-up on my symfony app. (application is Symfony 5.4, PHP 7.3, server is CentOS 7.9 with apache2.4)

I am also trying to use my own certificate and not a letsencrypt certification and I was wondering what was best (or the correct way of doing) :

- Do I put my symfony app on my server, run symfony:ca:install and change the certificates with my own certificates ? (If so, do I have to keep the same name and extension ?) and finally run symfony server:start ?
- Or do I update my httpd.conf and ssl.conf files and point on the public folder of my app then run httpd service ?

So far I have tried the two options :

I have tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144435/how-to-install-a-custom-certificate-in-symfony-server)  where I copied my .crt and .key and .p12 files, changed their name and extension via openssl to rootCA.pem for the .crt file and rootCA-key.pem for the .key file. But then when I run my app it tells me that it finds a certificate for root@serverName signed by Symfony dev cert and not the one I would like it to use (and so the server warns me that connexion is not secure).

I have also tried to modify my httpd.conf and ssl.conf to use the public folder of my app this way : (I used [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html#using-mod-php-php-cgi-with-apache-2-4) for this part).

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName serverName
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/myowncert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/myownkey.key

    <Directory /var/www/html/myproject/public>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  serverName
    ServerAlias serverName
    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/myproject/public>
                AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my ssl.conf file :

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/serverName-https.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/serverName-https.key
```

This solution was partly working, it could find my certificate and secure the connexion but it could not run my symfony app (it would read the index.php of the /var/www/html/index.php file)

Can anyone help ? Am I missing some basics ?

Comment: Under no circumstances should you ever run symfony:server in production.  Full stop.  Look at the docs for whatever server software you do decide to use to see how to use your certificates.

Comment: As Cerad says. Spin up an Apache server and copy your project files to the server and just use letsencrypt or zerossl for your tls certs. This is a good project to make certs more streamlined and simplified imo [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh).